# How to write the thinnest possible type wrapper

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    const T& in;
    Wrapper(const T& _in) : in(_in) {}

    operator const T&() const { return in; }
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<std::string> value("OMGOMGOMG");
    if(value == std::string("ads"))
        return 1;
}
```

And I get an error that there is no match for `operator==` with gcc/msvc - how can I get this code to work?

With type `int` it works but with `std::string` it doesn't.

**EDIT:**

I ended up writing them on my own - as separate templates with 2 arguments:

```
template<typename T> bool operator==(const WithContext<T>& lhs, const T& rhs){ return lhs.in == rhs; }
template<typename T> bool operator==(const T& lhs, const WithContext<T>& rhs){ return lhs == rhs.in; }
template<typename T> bool operator!=(const WithContext<T>& lhs, const T& rhs){ return lhs.in != rhs; }
template<typename T> bool operator!=(const T& lhs, const WithContext<T>& rhs){ return lhs != rhs.in; }
template<typename T> bool operator< (const WithContext<T>& lhs, const T& rhs){ return lhs.in <  rhs; }
template<typename T> bool operator< (const T& lhs, const WithContext<T>& rhs){ return lhs <  rhs.in; }
template<typename T> bool operator> (const WithContext<T>& lhs, const T& rhs){ return lhs.in >  rhs; }
template<typename T> bool operator> (const T& lhs, const WithContext<T>& rhs){ return lhs >  rhs.in; }
template<typename T> bool operator<=(const WithContext<T>& lhs, const T& rhs){ return lhs.in <= rhs; }
template<typename T> bool operator<=(const T& lhs, const WithContext<T>& rhs){ return lhs <= rhs.in; }
template<typename T> bool operator>=(const WithContext<T>& lhs, const T& rhs){ return lhs.in >= rhs; }
template<typename T> bool operator>=(const T& lhs, const WithContext<T>& rhs){ return lhs >= rhs.in; }
```

Comment: int is a primitive type, so it works

Comment: if you require any operator/operations for user defined type, then, you need to define them

Comment: Side note: do you realize that `Wrapper<std::string> value("OMGOMGOMG");` will leave you with an invalid value? It will construct a temporary `const std::string` instance, you store its reference but the object will be gone by the end of the constructor call.

Comment: @grek40 damn it you're right - I should make a copy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you desire the `Wrapper` to have an equality comparison to the underlying type, give it one.

```
template<typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    const T& in;
    Wrapper(const T& _in) : in(_in) {}

    operator const T&() const { return in; }

    // compare to the underlying type
    bool operator==(T const& cmp) const { return cmp == in; }
    // compare the this type
    bool operator==(Wrapper const& cmp) const { return cmp.in == in; }
};

int main() {
    Wrapper<std::string> value("OMGOMGOMG");
    if(value == std::string("ads"))
        return 1;
}
```

The sample code presented here is for illustration, to support the premis that the desired comparison functions should be implemented. In reality, the comparison functions would probably land up being non member functions to support a more natural syntax.

Comment: Is there a shortcut for that - like inheriting from some std class or to use some traits? Suppose I want all the operators...

And why does my code work for ```int``` and not ```std::string```?

Comment: You could try the inheritance, I would avoid it. Giving the `Wrapper` the operators you need, I would argue, is clearer in its intent, but it may be something of a personal preference.

Comment: On why it doesn't work with the class, you provide two conversion sequences from the `Wrapper` to the underlying `T`, the constructor and the conversion operator - which one should the compiler choose? On why it does work with an `int`, it is a primitive type - I don't have a C++ standard quote for you offhand.

Comment: @Niall the constructor is not at fault. You can mark it `explicit` and still the conversion operator will not be used

Comment: And one last thing - even if I provide the operators as members of the wrapper - then ```type == wrapper<type>``` wouldn't work - I guess I should supply the operators as template functions with 2 parameters? **EDIT:** just tried that - didn't work...

Comment: @onqtam. You would need to provide the operators for comparison for the `Wrapper` type as well. It sounds like you desire two forms of each operator, one for the underlying type `T` and one for the `Wrapper` type itself.

Comment: @grek40. The operators will need to be crafted to support the intended wrap and unwrapping functionality - I'm not going to assume too much on the OP code that wasn't posted. The second comparison is there to support the desire (as commented by the OP) to support the Wrapper class as well as the underlying type. Conflicting operators will naturally cause conflicts.